# html5 canvas javascript wait for user input

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I am very new to javascript. 
I am working a webgame. I am trying to use for loop to let players enter their names and select gamepiece by clicking. I'm struggling to make code to wait for user input (click on a game piece image) before moving on to the next player.

```
function GetPlayerNames(){
  for (var i=1; i<=NumberPlayers; i++) {

    ctxPlayers.fillStyle =  "blue";
    ctxPlayers.textAlign = "center";
    var PlayerName = prompt("Name");
    ctxPlayers.fillText (PlayerName + " Select Game Piece", cnvPlayers.width/2,cnvPlayers.height* (1/6));

    // here i want to wait for a player to click on a game piece image

  };
};
```

in vb.net version i used do while loop with application.doevents. It's my understanidng javascript doesn't have an equivalent, but i hope for a rather simple solution that will allow my to accomplish the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are not familiar with JavaScript, then learn it. This question is somehow asking people to write code for you. This is not how StackOverflow should work.

Comment: I am not asking for code. I am looking for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `prompt`, which stops the execution of the script, and then you need to wait for a click, but there's no way to stop the execution for that like you can with `prompt`.

A better approach would be to check the values of all player names and images each time there is a change in a name or an image is clicked.

Will not give you any code for that, learn how you'd do it, it should be enough to get you started. So please don't use prompt combined with click listeners, but create an input field.

Here's a super simple example:

```js
// keeping our input elements in a variable
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

// loop over them to attach them a keyup listener
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', checkNames);
}

// this function is called on each keyup event (and once in the beginning)
function checkNames() {
  var playersReady = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].value != "") {
      playersReady++; // increment the value if the input is not empty
    }
  }

  // output the message
  document.getElementById('status').textContent = "Waiting for " +
    (inputs.length - playersReady) + " more player" + 
    (inputs.length - playersReady == 1 ? "" : "s") + // this line is just for pluralizing
    "..." + 
    (inputs.length - playersReady == 0 ? "The game can start now!" : "");
}

// initial call, just so we get the first status message
// without needing a keyup event first
checkNames();
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Player1 name" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Player2 name" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Player3 name" />
<p id="status"></p>
```

You can expand this example by adding images, and keeping track of how many of them are selected, similarly to how I keep track of non-empty player names.

Once you get comfortable with that, a bit more advanced task would be to try creating boxes for player names directly on canvas and listening for focus and keyboard inputs on them, but that's a whole another question...

Answer (score 2):

Not required. When input occurs, the browser will call the JavaScript functions that you have attached to those events. Simply put, the browser has its own main loop that calls your code on a standardized set of conditions.

Let's say someone presses something on the keyboard. The browser will fire `keydown` and `keyup` events as the button is pressed and released. Also, if you use the statement `window.requestAnimationFrame(yourFunction);`, then `yourFunction()` will be called as early as possible in the next frame. If `yourFunction()` also calls `window.requestAnimationFrame(yourFunction);`, then `yourFunction()` will be your main loop.

In your case, most of your heavy code will be attached to the `mousedown`, `mouseup`, or `click` events. You should not need a main loop.

```
function yourClickHandler() {
  //Whatever happens when your gamepiece is clicked.
}

/*
 *  This attaches the click event to some element that you use as your gamepiece.
 *  If you're using Canvas, you will attach it to the canvas (instead of #GamePiece
 *  and then need to figure out what is in the pixel that you clicked on in it.
 */

document.getElementById("#GamePiece").addEventListener("click", yourClickHandler, false);
```

Your game can just sleep between user clicks, unless you need complex animations and stuff that cannot be done with CSS transitions and so forth. If it's, say, a turn-based strategy, then you can just make the piece look clicked, then sleep, then give it a destination, then sleep, then select something else, then sleep. Etc.

**If you do need complex animations and stuff...**

Then it is best to have `yourClickHandler()` do ***as little as possible***. Try to do nothing more than set a variable and return. Your `requestAnimationFrame()`-based draw/update functions should use those variables to perform the intense calculations then.

For instance, if you are making a character walk, let all the walking / falling / etc. happen once per frame. Just keep track of whether the button is pressed or not (or how far a joystick is tilted, etc.)

The reason for this is simple: Drawing happens once per frame, but input events might happen several times. You want to draw to the screen only once per draw to the monitor. Also, input events can happen at *any time*. You don't want a big calculation to happen a tenth of a millisecond before the frame is needed by the monitor. You want that to happen as early in the frame as possible.

Comment: I think you went a bit too broad here, without focusing on the question.